# Load average relation to cpu threads and cpu cores

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, central-processing-unit, cpu-usage

Is load average related to CPU ThreadS OR CPU core?

i am having a xenon cpu with 8 cores and 16 threads.

How much can be the acceptable load average?

Sometimes Load AVerage reaches 11.

so does that means load average upto 16 is with in acceptable range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HyperThreaded CPU cores aren't quite full CPU cores, so I'd probably be concerned around a load of 12 or so on a system with 8 physical cores. From a monitoring perspective, your load threshold is technically 16.

Of course, this all depends on what's causing the load increase. If it's all CPU-processing activity, that's different than if some component of the high load is the result of the I/O subsystem and storage.

Comment: Factually wrong. A Hyper-V CPU is mapped to a Logical CPU core of te underlying processor - with Hyper-Threading that is a CPU thread as this is what a Logical core is physically. I never liked load averages as any indicator - at the end a CPU is overlaoded only when it does not do what Needs to be done fast enough. Mabe m HPC Background gets into my way - my CPU's often are 100% load for hours at a time.

Comment: @TomTom The OP isn't speaking about Hyper-V. They are speaking about an Ubuntu system with what's probably a 5500/5600-series Intel Xeon CPU. Storage may be a factor in their setup, thus the question about what's influencing the I/O load. In HPC and financials, we knew not to schedule on HyperThreaded CPU cores in the first place. Don't get self-righteous.